# memcache.Client not setting cache values on GAE python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I am trying to add memcache to my webapp deployed on GAE, and to do this I am using `memcache.Client()` to prevent damage from any racing conditions:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache

client = memcache.Client()
class BlogFront(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):       
        global client 
        val = client.gets(FRONT_PAGE_KEY)
        posts = list()

        if val is not None:
            posts = list(val)
        else:
            posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Post order by created desc limit 10")
            client.cas(FRONT_PAGE_KEY, list(posts))

        self.render('front.html', posts = posts)
```

To test the problem I have a front page for a blog that displays the 10 most recent entries. If there is nothing in the cache, I hit the DB with a request, otherwise I just present the cached results to the user.

The problem is that no matter what I do, I always get `val == None`, thus meaning that I always hit the database with a useless request.

I have sifted through the documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass
- http://neopythonic.blogspot.pt/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html

And it appears that I am doing everything correctly. What am I missing?

(PS: I am a python newb, if this is a retarded error, please bear with me xD )

Comment: don't worry about race conditions right now. Just make it work as simply as you can using "add" and "get". And if what you are trying to save is over the limit for the size of a single object in memcache that might explain your issue.

Comment: If I replace the `client.gets(key)` and `client.cas(key, val)` by `memcache.get(key)` and `memcache.set(key, val)` everything works perfectly. The problem is using memcache.Client and the race conditions are a real problem :S

Comment: right you are then. Your "newb" threw me :P Dunno then...

Comment: Is there really a race condition ?  How has it manifested itself in your situation ?  You aren't really updating a value that needs to be atomic. The only real problem that could occurr is more of a dogpile effect.  Also you don't even appear to be using CAS correctly as you current approach won't protect against a race condition, it will only detect it. You need a loop and a retry, as per the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/  and CAS only updates, it doesn't add.  See the examples in the doc I have linked here

Comment: Also are posts the only dynamic element of the page ? If so why cache the posts and re-render the page, why not cache the rendered page ?

Comment: And one more question, why you are making `client` global, and not instantiating `memcache.Client` inside your handler ?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood: I say this because I have gotten negative reputation in python question considered "newb" questions by other members.

Comment: @TimHoffman: This is a simplified version of the code. At this point I just want a basic example working without all the juicy stuff that comes next :S And, caching the rendered page is the next step, but I will never get that far unless I get this simple example working. You have a nice eye :P

Comment: So you need to distinguish between an `add` and a `cas` operation which means get first, if fails, do an add, if succeeds us a `cas` however you have no logic to determine if you should `cas`.

Comment: Why would I want to use an add when it does not protect me against any real race conditions? If the cas is successful, it will set the memcache and return true, otherwise false. This is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from google.appengine.api import memcache

```
class BlogFront(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):       
        client = memcache.Client() 
        client.gets(FRONT_PAGE_KEY)
        client.cas(FRONT_PAGE_KEY, 'my content')
```

For a reason I cannot yet possible understand, the solution lies in having a `gets` right before having a `cas` call ...

I think I will stick with the memcache non-thread-safe version of the code for now ...

Comment: Look at this line on github: https://github.com/linsomniac/python-memcached/blob/master/memcache.py#L1044

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the client.cas call is failing because there is no object.  Perhaps client.cas only works to update and existing object (not to set a new object if there is none currently)?  You might try client.add() (which will fail if an object already exists with the specified key, which I think is what you want?) instead of client.cas()

Comment: I want to use `cas` because cas protects against race conditions, while `add` does not :S Also, if there is no Object, then client would be None, and an exception would occur right? That is not the case :S

Comment: I disagree that add does not protect against race conditions.  Add "[s]ets a key's value, if and only if the item is not already in memcache." (from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_add)

Comment: re: "Also, if there is no Object, then client would be None, and an exception would occur right?" No, I'm not sure why you think the client would be None in this case.  The client is created by "memcache.Client()".  *val* is None if there is no object.

Comment: This piece of code is used to update the cache. Add does not allow that, while cas allows that, ie, I can update the value of a key using cas.